# Are variables always in brackets or just × (times)?

Tags: linear-algebra, education

It has been a while since I had basic mathematics, let alone algebra, but I am trying to relearn it again. As I recall correctly, my teacher always said that if you have $xy$ in an expression (2 variables without an operation between them), it's exactly the same as $x\times y$. Now I need to evaluate an expression, in which I have the wrong answer, but I am not completely sure when to use the brackets.

> Question: Evaluate $-5x^2-(x+y)$, where $x=-2$ and $y=5$.

My way would be (step by step):

\begin{align}-5x^2-(x+y)&=-5\times-2^2-(-2+5) \tag{fill in variables}\\
&=-5\times-2^2-3 \tag{brackets first} \\
&=-5\times-4-3 \tag{exponents second}\\
&=20-3 \\
&= 17\end{align}

According to the answer from the answer paper and different step by step calculators, it should be:

\begin{align}-5x^2-(x+y)&=-5(x)^2-(x+y) \tag{put brackets around $x$}\\
&=-5(-2)^2-(-2+5) \tag{fill in variables}\\
&=-5(-2)^2-3 \tag{brackets first}\\
&=-5\times4-3 \tag{$\dagger$}\\
&=-20-3 \\
&== -23`\end{align}

where $\dagger$ is because $(-2)^2 = (-2)(-2) = 4$

Is it therefore safe to say if you have variables in an algebraic expression it is always between brackets?

Comment: Well $x^2$ is $x\times x$, so if $x=-2$, then $x^2=x\times x = (-2)\times (-2) =(-2)^2$.

Comment: Yes, it is never wrong to replace all $x$ by $(x)$ before substituting in the values.

Comment: True, this is the main reason I am in doubt. In pre-algebra I learned that `2² = 2*2 = 4`, `-2² = - 2*2 = -4`, `-(2)² = - (2)(2) = -4`and `(-2)² = (-2)(-2) = 4`. This might be wrong, but this how I learned it from different YouTube channels.

Comment: It's not just minus signs, any expression other than a positive number has this problem. Suppose you want to substitute $x=2+3$ into $x^2$, you want $(2+3)^2 = 25$, not $2+3^2 = 11$

Comment: * immediately followed by - is not allowed.

Comment: @Wouter This makes sense. So it's safe to say that all operations and values except positive are always in brackets (e.g. `5² = 25`, and if it would be negative it would be `-(5)² = -25`)?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I understand, the thing I was doubting was that according to my pre-algebra `x² = x*x`, but when it is a negative number it would be `-x² = - x*x` (not double minus). With these explanations I should see it as `(x)²`, which will always result in `(x)(x)`, even if the value is negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get confused by viewing the evaluation of an expression as a matter of gradually replacing symbols in a formula by other symbols. Doing so is extremely convenient and a great timesaver, but only as long as you know where you need to insert parentheses in the right places such that you won't get nonsense out of it. And the way to know that is to know that **symbol manipulation is not the *real* meaning of the expression**.

Rather, an expression is a *recipe* for which calculation you perform. When you have an expression such as
$$ -5x^2 + (x+y) $$
this is really nothing more nor less than a compact way to write down these instructions:

1. Find the value of $x$.
2. Raise the result of step 1 to the second power.
3. Multiply the result of step 2 by five.
4. Take the negative of the result of step 3.
5. Find the value of $x$ (once again!)
6. Find the value of $y$.
7. Subtract the result of step 6 from the result of step 5.
8. Add the result of step 4 to the result of step 7.
9. The result of step 8 is, by definition, the value of the entire expression.

Now when you **actually follow the recipe**, it is clear that in your case with $x=-2$, the result of step 1 becomes negative two, and therefore the result of step 2 becomes *positive four*.  The result of the value of $x$ is always what is squared in step 2.

So if you want to use symbolic rewriting to keep track of where in the recipe you are, you need to be sure to insert parentheses in the expression as necessary such that *the steps of the original recipe what we haven't done yet still stay the same*.

If you just replace the symbol $x$ *textually* by the symbols "$-2$" and get
$ -2^2 $ for $x^2$, you've introduced a "negate the result" step *after* the "take the square" step, so you rewriting does not preserve the meaning. In order to preserve the meaning we need to insert parentheses to get $(-2)^2$.

**This is the point of parentheses:** To make clear how the calculation steps fit together and which results are input to which other steps.

Part of the source of the confusion here is that we don't have a single symbol that means "negative two". If we want an expression for that number, the best we can do is to write it $-2$ -- but *that* notation is really a two-step recipe:

1. Take the number two.
2. Take the negative of the result of step 1.

Inserting this *recipe* in place of all of the "find the value of $x$" in the original one means that we now have steps from *different recipes* in the same list of steps. So in order to write down those steps as an algebraic expression, we might need to write *new* parentheses to clarify the relation between steps that came from different sources:

$$ -5(-2)^2 + (x+y) $$

---

(All of the PEMDAS stuff that some school teachers place an inordinate importance on are not more than the convention for how to get from the algebraic expression to a step-by-step recipe. Even though the rules say "parentheses first", nobody cares whether you *actually* carry out the addition in step 8 before you begin steps 2, etc -- the addition will give the same result no matter when you carry it out, as long as you're clear on *which numbers it is you add*. The importance of the parenthesis in the original expression says that the *result* of adding $x$ and $y$ is one of the *inputs* to the other addition, and not the other way around.)

Comment: Instead of a linear recipe I would say an expression represents a tree with numbers or variables at the leaves and operations at the branches. I think elementary schools even use these trees before writing them down using parentheses. Maybe an answer using trees would be more appropriate. I don't have the time to prepare one myself though :-/

Comment: @Christoph: Yes, that would be even better, though at the risk of confusing lay readers who are not used to thinking in trees.

Answer (score 2):

When you say that filling in the variable $x=-2$ and $y=5$ results in:

> 1. `-5*-2²-(-2+5)` (fill in variables)

you are changing the *unary* operator '-' (that takes a number $x$ and outputs $-x$ ... this is what the '-' does to the '2' in '-2') into a *binary* operator that subtracts a number from another number.  That is really the mistake you make here. So the problem is not with the $xy$ being short for $x * y$, but how the minus sign is being used.